# How to disable the reload in collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am having UI collection view multiple cells.I am dynamically showing data from the web service.Whenever I scroll the collection view the data automatically changing.I want to disable the feature.

My code.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    //return [names count];
    return myObject.count;
}

- (UIView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     NSString*  statusfield = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpDict objectForKey:@"StatusId"]];
      if([statusfield isEqualToString:@"13"])
    {
         [cell.mySegmentedControl setTitle:@"SEND TO ADMIN" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
         [cell.mySegmentedControl setTitle:@"EVALUATE" forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    }
    if([statusfield isEqualToString:@"5"])
    {
       [cell.mySegmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];
       [cell.mySegmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    }
    if([statusfield  isEqualToString: @"1"])
    {
        [cell.mySegmentedControl setTitle:@"ACCEPT" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
        [cell.mySegmentedControl setTitle:@"REJECT" forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    }
}
```

when I scroll the mycollection view.The above segments values automatically changed because of reload function.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how its posible, it means some where you refresh your array check once

Comment: I think It's not problem of refresh it's collection view problem of "dequeuing". Are you facing problem like while scrolling data get overlapped then try this.
for (UILabel *lbl in cell.contentView.subviews)
    {
        if ([lbl isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            [lbl removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
    for (UIImageView *img in cell.contentView.subviews)
    {
        if ([img isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
        {
            [img removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

This method may be helps you which reloads the data according to your items.

```
- (void)reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)indexPaths
```

Comment: How can I use this method in my collection view ?

Comment: [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:x section:0]];

Comment: So shall I remove this method - (UIView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ ?